# MySQL with Many IF condition parameters

Tags: mysql, performance

I have below query, I do understand the how the normal IF Conditions works however below one is bit confusing to know what its really doing?

```
SELECT * FROM `client` 
WHERE IF( date_due < due_date_none, date_due, due_date_none) < date(now()) 
&& DATEDIFF(NOW(), IF( date_due < due_date_none, date_due, due_date_none)) < 500
```

Can anyone let me know what the IF condition is doing here? Or are there a better more readable way to write this query?

Comment: for `IF()`, if the first argument is true then the second argument is returned, otherwise the second argument is returned. 

so `IF( date_die < due_date_none, date_due, due_date_none)` will be either the same value as `date_due` or `due_date_none` depending on whether or not `date_due` is less than `due_date_none`.

Comment: Suggest using date arithmetic:  `WHERE some_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 500 DAY`

Comment: @Jhecht would you like to add your answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `IF()`, if the first argument is true then the second argument is returned, otherwise the third argument is returned. so `IF( date_due < due_date_none, date_due, due_date_none)` will be either the same value as `date_due` or `due_date_none` depending on whether or not `date_due` is less than `due_date_none`

Comment: isn't that statement should be "if the first argument is true then the second argument is returned, otherwise the third argument is returned", It returns the third arg, if the first condition is false isn't it? please clarify

Comment: Correct. I had made the original comment (which i had copy/pasted) while on mobile and didn't notice the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

To make it more readable, consider replacing the IF() with a LEAST(), as the IF() just returns the smallest/oldest date.

DATEDIFF() will give you a negative number if the second parameter is greater than the first, so there is no point in first checking if the dates are in the past, if later you will check for a positive number in DATEDIFF().

And it seems to me you want to check if the smallest of date_due and due_date_none, is between (but not including) today and 500 days ago. I think you don't even need DATEDIFF() for that.

Also, a little formatting could never hurt.

So here is what I suggest:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `client` 
WHERE
    LEAST(date_due, due_date_none) BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 499) AND SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)
```

EDIT:

If date_due or due_date_none is a DATETIME containing hours, minutes and seconds, then put the LEAST() inside DATE() to remove the hours, minutes and seconds:

```
DATE(LEAST(date_due, due_date_none)) BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 499) AND SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)
```